# How to dynamically generate html list from json array received via ajax call?

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am a Django novice attempting to build an app that allows users to add tracks to a playlist.
I use sessions to generate a list of track id strings in a view and return an http response with the serialized array. The problem is that trying to iterate through the array in the template to build an ordered list does not format properly. It displays as a python list instead of the expected bulleted html list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

the Div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<div id="playlist">
<ol>
{% for track in playlist %}
    <li>{{track}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
</div>
</html>
```

the javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('submit', '.track_form', function() {
        var $form = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: $form.attr('action'),
                data: $form.serialize(),
                type: $form.attr('method'),
                success: function (data) {

                    $("#playlist").html(data);
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    console.log('There was a problem');
                }
             });
             return false;    
         });
</script>
```

the view

```
def artistpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session_playlist = request.session.get('session_playlist', [])
        tname = str(request.POST.get('track_name'))
        session_playlist.append(tname)
        request.session['session_playlist'] = session_playlist

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(session_playlist))
```

Comment: But you're not iterating over the result returned from the Ajax call. You just dump it straight into the #playlist div.

Comment: How to iterate over the result? I suspected that was the problem but I am not sure how to approach the proper solution

Comment: Vivek has shown you one way to do it. Another is to change your view so that it renders a standalone template fragment, similar to the inner part of the HTML you have already, and returns that rather than JSON; then you can insert it into the HTML directly.

Comment: Interesting. So i would have two html files and insert one into the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using ajax call to make request, you need to create html list in javascript code. Django template will not work in this case. Once your ajax call returns success you can create list html like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('submit', '.track_form', function() {
    var $form = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: $form.serialize(),
            type: $form.attr('method'),
            success: function (data) {
                var list_html = "<ol>";
                for( var i=0; i <data.length; i++) {
                   list_html += "<li>" + data[i] + "</li>";
                 }
                list_html += "</ol>"
                $("#playlist").html(list_html);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('There was a problem');
            }
         });
         return false;    
     });
```

Your html should look like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <div id="playlist">
  </div>
</html>
```

So your view should look something like this.

```
def artistpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session_playlist = request.session.get('session_playlist', [])
        tname = str(request.POST.get('track_name'))
        session_playlist.append(tname)
        request.session['session_playlist'] = session_playlist

       return HttpResponse(json.dumps(session_playlist), content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: Thanks Vivek! I will try this and report back

Comment: it works but it prints every character in the string as a new list item, instead of every string in the list. original ajax data looked like ['track1_id', 'track2_id', 'track3_id']

Comment: can you paste data that you received in ajax response here ?

Comment: probably you replace this data.session_playlist.length by data.length and data.session_playlist[i] by data[i] then it should work fine.

Comment: the data returns as ["Life Round Here", "Pembroke"] and will add another track each time a user presses submit on one of the forms

Comment: I have updated the answer .. can you please try now ?

Comment: it still prints every character, including brackets, quotes, and commas. Does the data need to be processed before iteration?

Comment: Yeah got it.. so while sending response you need to specify content type. You need to pass content_type="application/json" while sending HttpResponse.

Comment: @arshadic - Facing the same problem. I am sending a variable **legData** of numeric values (as a **list**) thru' ajax call to Django views such as `[1406, 1409]`. If I print to the console with `print(legData)` I get the output as `[1406,1409]`. But if I try to parse individual values of the list with `for idx, xLeg in enumerate(legData):` `print(idx, xLeg)`, gives output of individual chars such as `[, 1, 4, 0, 6 ` and so on against the indices 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. (**square brackets & comma are also being output as in your case). Could u pls suggest how may I get individual values eg 1406 etc.**