# AJAX request to Django view pulls data but list not populating

Tags: jquery, django

Trying to populate a side bar with session status from api server. Having trouble following a modified example shown here:

[How to dynamically generate html list from json array received via ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45403299/how-to-dynamically-generate-html-list-from-json-array-received-via-ajax-call)

I'm able to get the console to log the dict values but when I try to populate a list following the example it fails to show anything on the page. I also don't see any dev console errors.

HTML:

```
<div id="sessionstatuslist">
        </div>
```

Ajax Function:

```
function sessionStatus(){
    var _url = "ajax/get_sessionstatus";
    var request = $.ajax({
        "url": _url,
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        data: {},
    success: function (data) {
                var list_html = "<ol>";
                for( var i=0; i <data.length; i++) {
                   list_html += "<li>" + data[i] + "</li>";
                 }
                list_html += "</ol>"
                $("#sessionstatuslist").html(list_html);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('there was a problem');
            }
         });
         return false;    
     };
```

View:

```
def Getsessionstatus(request):
    sessionstatus_list = {'session 1': 'running', 'session 2': 'idle',}
    data = sessionstatus_list
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: Did you see what console.log(data) shows?

Comment: yes, if I switch the success function to console.log(data); I get {session 1: "running", session 2: "idle"}
session 2: "idle"
session 1: "running"
__proto__: Object

Comment: dont switch success function. Add console.log() in your success function and see if your console works **in the** success function

Comment: I get "<ol></ol>" returned, no data inside the list

Comment: add ```console.log(data[i])``` in the for loop to see it is iterating list.

Comment: That helped, thank you. I was able to solve my problem. The property values of the object were not accessible to the function without using a method to return them...? Seems t work.

Answer (score 0):

The fix was very easy,

```
function sessionStatus(){
    var _url = "ajax/get_sessionstatus";
    var request = $.ajax({
        "url": _url,
        dataType : 'json',
        type : 'GET',
        data: {},
    success: function (data) {
                var list_html = "<ol>";
                data = Object.values(data);
                for( var i=0; i <data.length; i++) {
                   list_html += "<li>" + data[i] + "</li>";
                 }
                list_html += "</ol>"
                $("#sessionstatuslist").html(list_html);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                console.log('there was a problem');
            }
         });
         return false;    
     };
```

Was able to add Object.values() method to enumerate the property values of the array. It seems to work this way. There is probably a better way with the Jquery Map() method.